# NoClassDefFoundError using castor unmarshalling

Tags: java, spring-batch, unmarshalling, castor

I'm getting a very strange NoClassDefFoundError using Castor inside of Spring Batch to unmarshall XML. Here's the stack trace before I show anything else:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/test/STLTRANSACTIONINFO (wrong name: com/example/test/StlTransactionInfo)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
```

It seems to me that the exception is saying that for some reason it's looking for my class name in all capital letters, but then when it says "wrong name:" it has the right class name.

Here's my mapping file:

```
<!DOCTYPE mapping PUBLIC "-//EXOLAB/Castor Mapping DTD Version 1.0//EN" "http://castor.org/mapping.dtd">
<mapping>
    <class name="com.example.test.ExtResponseTransaction">
        <map-to xml="EXTRESPONSETRANSACTION" />
    </class>
    <class name="com.example.test.StlTransactionInfo">
        <map-to xml="STLTRANSACTIONINFO" />
        <field name="keyTranID" type="string">
            <bind-xml name="KEYTRANID" node="element"/>
        </field>
    </class>
    <class name="com.example.test.StlTransactionData">
        <map-to xml="STLTRANSACTIONDATA"/>
        <field name="responseString" type="string">
            <bind-xml name="RESPONSE" node="element"/>
        </field>
    </class>
    <class name="com.example.test.CSIDResponse">
        <map-to xml="RESPONSE"/>
    </class>
</mapping>
```

Any ideas? Even if I comment the entire mapping definition for StlTransactionInfo I get the same error.

Comment: The only time I've seen the wrong name message from a NoClassDefFoundError is when the source code is packaged, but the compiled class doesn't exist in a directory which mirrors the package declaration. You should check that inside of your jar file, or the build path for the app that com/example/test/ exists and has your compiled class in it.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but not the case here. Just verified that the directory structure matched the package structure.

Comment: Just saw your edit and double-checked the maven-generated jar and the class is in the right spot.

Comment: Is the jar file containing this class the executable jar? If not, check to make sure that the executable jar has a classpath entry in its manifest.mf file pointing to the jar containing the StlTransactionInfo class.

Comment: Is it possible this is a bug with castor? Are there any workarounds I could try, as in a different syntax in the mapping file or anything?

Comment: A quick search of NoClassDefFound and castor yields several results that could be related, but from what I looked at they are all problems with spring supported versions of castor, and this seems a little different :/

Comment: Well I am doing this inside of spring, so that could be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I simply renamed the java classes to be all uppercase, and that did the trick.

This is definitely a hacky solution that does the trick for now, but I figured I'd post it so if anyone runs into the same issue and needs it working ASAP they can apply the quick fix. In the coming days I'll try to nail down the real root cause, and will update the answer if I find anything.